# Get around deprecated quanteda texts() function

Tags: r, quanteda

I am trying to replicate [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/isq/article/65/3/852/6278490?#supplementary-data)

In the tokens.R script it's cleaning up the corpus with the following command:

```
texts(corp) <- stri_replace_all_regex(texts(corp), "^[\\p{Lu}\\p{Z}]+(.{0,30}?)(\\(.{0,50}?\\))?(--)", "")
```

Which yields the following error message:

```
Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  'names' attribute [387896] must be the same length as the vector [4]
In addition: Warning message:
'texts.corpus' ist veraltet.
Benutzen Sie stattdessen 'as.character'
Siehe help("Deprecated")
```

So I naively apply the 'as.character' function like this:

```
as.character(corp) <- stri_replace_all_regex(as.character(corp), "^[\\p{Lu}\\p{Z}]+(.{0,30}?)(\\(.{0,50}?\\))?(--)", "")
```

Which yields the following error

```
Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  'names' attribute [387896] must be the same length as the vector [4]
```

I tried some other things, like only adressing $documents within the corpus or turning the corpus into a vector but none of that really worked.

How can I get around this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "corpus" being loaded in the linked .R file `tokens.R` is using a very old format corpus object (from `data/corpus_nytimes_summary.RDS`).

You can convert this into a new format corpus using:

```r
corp <- corpus(corp)
```

Then replace the texts using this approach:

```r
corp[] <- stri_replace_all_regex(corp, "^[\\p{Lu}\\p{Z}]+(.{0,30}?)(\\(.{0,50}?\\))?(--)", "")
```

The use of `corp[]` replaces the character part of `corp` without stripping the additional attributes (metadata and docvars) that make the character object `corp` a **quanteda** corpus.